# Removing CSS class with jQuery depending on scroll position

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll

I have tried working from someone else's answer in another post but I don't know how to remove the .scroll class when the scroll position is back to the top of the screen.

It starts with no background colour, then disappears when you start to scroll. This is great. Then it only appears when you scroll up the screen, with the .scroll class on it. However, when you reach the very top of the screen it should remove .scroll totally and return to having no background.

```
    // Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 6;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up scroll');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    } 

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

CSS

```
  body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
}

.scroll {
    background: #666;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}

main {
   background:url(
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
   ) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}

footer { background: #ddd;}
 * { color: transparent}
```

HTML

```
<header class="nav-down">
    This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
    This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
    This is your footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154753/add-bottom-box-shadow-to-the-menu-on-scrollup-and-scrolldown/17155001#17155001

Comment: `st` should = zero if you have scrolled all the way to the top. Or, I guess in this case, if `st < navbarHeight`.

Comment: There are no any line to remove `.scroll` in the above code... Just like what Turnip said, maybe you can add a condition to check whether the user is on the very top of the screen, and then call `.removeClass('scroll')` in that condition.